# Does the amount of RAM have an impact on performance?

Tags: memory, hardware-rec, ddr3, ddr2

Can anyone tell me how much difference there would be between a 3 GB DDR3 RAM and a 2 GB DDR3 RAM, performance wise. And can we, based on performance, compare to any DDR2 RAM's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance wise, if the specification is the same on speed, you will only see a difference when performing high end tasks that require a lot of memory.

As for the speed to DDR2 memory, we cannot really compare without other facts such as the speed of memory and latency.

[Here is a basic test](http://www.anandtech.com/show/2232/7) from Anandtech that shows various memory modules compared - you can see that the performance on most is only marginally different in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

This depends. If you are running a Core i7 and the 3GB is in triple channel, the benefits will be significant compared to the 2GB which would probably be in dual channel. Here is an example benchmark comparing the two:

[image]

Comment: But is the difference noticeable?

Comment: @Quack - Depends on what you're doing. I do a lot of CAD work and it is definitely noticeable.