# How to trade off amount of RAM vs RAM speed?

Tags: memory, speed

I have an HTPC running Ubuntu 12.04.  I've got a low-power AMD Sempron 140 CPU and 1GB of DDR2 800 RAM.
For playing video and so on, it's great, but it's a little slow when it comes to stuff like web browsing, software upgrades, and running the Unity user interface.

I know that my web browser of choice, Google Chrome, likes to hog memory, so I'm thinking of an upgrade.  If I put in 2GB of DDR2 667 RAM, is the system likely to feel faster overall, even though individual memory accesses will be slower?  Or am I better off keeping the DDR2 800 RAM even though it's only 1GB?

More generally, how much improvement in the responsiveness of the system can I expect by increasing RAM speed?

**ANSWER**: Amount of RAM definitely matters, but RAM speed doesn't matter.  Definitive measurements from [Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ram-speed-tests,1807.html).  Those interested in this problem should see the closely related question [RAM speed: How does it impact performance?](https://superuser.com/questions/204694)

Comment: This has been addressed several times on the site. More RAM is better, for almost all conditions.

Comment: @RandolphWest: can you point to any specific questions?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/182084/will-adding-more-ram-speed-up-my-computer http://superuser.com/questions/204694/ram-speed-how-does-it-impact-performance http://superuser.com/questions/164765/does-the-amount-of-ram-have-an-impact-on-performance http://superuser.com/questions/398320/adding-ddr2-1066mhz-to-ddr2-800mhz-memory